# Dominant eigenvalue definition -- is this paper wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology

I have been reading this paper by [Neubert et al. (2004) on calculating reactivities of dynamical models](https://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/threshold_articles/Neubertetal2004.pdf). On page 31, equation 11, they define the two matrices:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -10\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 15 \\
0 & -10\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

and claim that both matrices "have the same dominant eigenvalue" of $\lambda_{1} = -1$.

It was my understanding that the dominant eigenvalue has the be the greatest in absolute value (i.e. magnitude), which would make $\lambda_{1} = -10$.

Can anyone clear this up for me? Thanks

Comment: I think "dominant eigenvalue" in the paper's context possibly refers to the eigenvalue with the maximum real part, rather than the eigenvalue with the maximum modulus (which is the usual meaning). This is probably justified when one's main concern is, for instance, to identify which exponential term decays the slowest.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. If $\lambda_1,...., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix with $|\lambda_1| \ge |\lambda_2| \ge ....|\lambda_n|$, then $\lambda_1$ is the dominant eigenvalue.